# What is the SwiftUI sheet view equivalent in UIKit?

Tags: swiftui, uikit

SwiftUI can easily present a [sheet view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)) on top of the existing review when a condition is met (see screen record below). What is the sheet component equivalent in UIKit?

Tried to Google a result and it looks like there is a sheet related view called [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactionsheet), but that does not seem like the right UI control.

[image]

#### REFERENCE

Example of how to achieve the same behavior with UIKit.

[iOS 14 navigation bar title is not displayed in UINavigationController created programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64411359/ios-14-navigation-bar-title-is-not-displayed-in-uinavigationcontroller-created-p/64411526?noredirect=1#comment113896678_64411526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just [another UIViewController presented **modally**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) with a [Done UIBarButtonItem on the right side](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/systemitem/done).