# iOS 14 navigation bar title is not displayed in UINavigationController created programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios14

iOS 14.2, when I tried to present a NavigationController controller programmatically with the code snippet below.

```
@objc private func handleClick() {
    let viewController = MyViewController()
    
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The bar title in the new controller won't get rendered. Am I missing anything?

```
class MyViewController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "TEST" // NOT WORK
        self.navigationItem.title = "Title" // NOT WORK
    }
}
```

[image]

Also tried the code snippet below to nest a regular View Controller into an UINavigableController but the title is still not rendered.

```
@objc private func handleHelpClick() {
    let innerVC = MyInnerViewController()
    innerVC.title = "TEST"
    let viewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: innerVC)
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: can you try inside the viewdidappear rather than viewdidload ?

Comment: @madara it behaves the same, not title rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says:

> A navigation controller builds the contents of the navigation bar dynamically using the navigation item objects (instances of the UINavigationItem class) associated with the view controllers on the navigation stack.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller

So from my understanding you have to set the title for your `UIViewController` itself instead for the `UINavigationController`.

**Example:**

```
class MyViewController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.setTitle("Display NavVC", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(displayNavVC), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        configureButton()
    }
    
    private func configureButton() {
        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc
    private func displayNavVC() {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.title = "abc"
        let navigationVC = MyViewController(rootViewController: vc)
        
        self.present(navigationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it also not have the title rendered somehow

Comment: Thank you so much for the demo. let me give another try on your example.

Comment: Tried the provided example and it works in the Playground.

Answer (score 0):

@finebel's answer in Playground

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.setTitle("Display NavVC", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(displayNavVC), for: .touchDown)
        return btn
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureButton()
    }
    
    private func configureButton() {
        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc
    private func displayNavVC() {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.title = "abc"
        let navigationVC = MyViewController(rootViewController: vc)
        
        self.present(navigationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

[image]