# How to make such an animation of page transition? [Mobile]

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, mobile-application

Please check this page transition animation
[image]

I think that it is pretty standard and I see it quite often in many different apps. Maybe someone can **tell me how it is called?** Cause i can`t figure it out how to implement it.

I see that previous screen becomes smaller and gains rounded corners, also the status bar becomes black. But how to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the SwiftUI sheet view equivalent in UIKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410722/what-is-the-swiftui-sheet-view-equivalent-in-uikit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a modal bottom sheet.
you can use [modal_bottom_sheet package](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) to generate modal bottom sheets using these functions:

Material Design Style:

```
showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Container(),
)
```

or Cupertino Style:

```
showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Container(),
)
```

Some other packages can help you implement what you're looking for, but this one has a huge difference in likes numbers, it has been recently updated,  and I used it about 2 years ago in a project so it's been actively supported.